# Multiple websites hosted in the same app pool

Tags: configuration, multisite, iis, multitenancy

Is it possible to have two or more Sitecore instances with different code bases running in the same (single) application pool?

Comment: I've updated my answer below based on a reminder from Richard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore is not designed to work with multiple individual instances in a single AppDomain. @RichardSeal reminded me that it makes use of shared (singleton) objects that would conflict between the two applications. These are used to improve performance and aid in caching certain resources, but make coexistence of two applications impossible.

Comment: You are also forgetting some major things like pre-fetch cache, all the application singletons like all the pipeline processors and other things like that. They are not just disadvantages - it would never work properly with 2 instances.

Comment: @RichardSeal - thanks for the reminders about that. I completely forgot about all the shared objects across the application; I was so focused on simply the server configuration. I've updated my answer accordingly.